# how to load a component, for each time when the function calls?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular5

I am using angular and I am trying to do reusable actions like bulk updates,bulk deletes,bulk deactivates.

I used all these actions in another component and want to used it as generic method.

Which means, i have two components: parent component and child component.

**Parent Component:**

In parent component , I am using a table(each row with checkbox).
 In check box I used a method,

```
  rowDataCheck(event, rowData) {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      this.groupList.push(rowData);
     } else {
      this.groupList = this.groupList.filter(item => item.id !== rowData.id);
     } 
  }
```

And the value is storing in `grouplist[]`. When page onloads(ngOnint) the `groupList=[]`. 
for eg:-

```
1. when ngOnit() loads = this.grouplist=[];

2. when I check 1st row = this.grouplist=[1];

3. when I check 2st row = this.grouplist=[1,2];

4. Unchecking and checking changes the groupList value(conditions give above)
```

**Child component:**

After the checkbox selection I want to pass the groupList value into child component.

**Problem::**

For passing the values from parent to child I used @input method.. But the child component is working only when the page loads.. I need to pass the value from parent to child when the checkbox selects for each time.

Please check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-oui6mj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: can anybody help me?

Comment: ```when the checkbox selects``` -> subscribe on the event -> do what you need

Comment: What do you mean by "the child component is working only when the page loads". Input is supposes to work any time the parent change the associated value. Do you have a onPush defined on the child? Can we have some code sample?

Comment: @yoannAugen  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-oui6mj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts...   please check this.. For your understanding I used console.log in child component.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you use array in the @Input. It's referred type and you can use it in your child component at any moment. It would work and shows actual to that moment state of your @Input.

If you want add some universality to your child components, I can recommend to use abstract class with methods as extension.

Comment: can you help me to do with abstract class with methods as extension.

Answer (score 0):

I would instead bind the checkboxes with a property and pass the entire list to child where I can do all the processing (in a separate service preferably).

With this you will always have the up to date data available to the child.

Here is the stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mtdavn

Comment: Not able to open this https://angular-ivy-oui6mj.stackblitz.io... Can you do me a favour...Can you share me the code??

Comment: @AngelReji My bad, updated the answer with editor URL: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mtdavn

Comment: @Manish..I dont see any changes in  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-oui6mj

Comment: @AngelReji The correct editor URL: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mtdavn

Answer (score 0):

The child component will not be aware an array has changed if the reference to it didn't change.

When you do a push(), the reference does not change. You have to do an immutable update of the list. So replace the

```
this.groupList.push(rowData.email);
```

by

```
this.groupList = [...this.groupList, rowData.email];
```

for example...

To check the changes in the child component, you can't put your console.log in the ngOnInit. This method is only called once, at the really start. Check it in the ngOnChange or directly displaying it in the template.